# Hibernate NonUniqueObjectException on merge() , update()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I get this errror while updating an objects by using method update()
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
when i use method merge() I get this error
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session.
Please help.

Comment: Good for you. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the 'hashCode' and 'equals' methods right, see [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode?_sscc=t). Take care not to use the id as the only unique property -> Separating object id and business key.

Comment: the methods are already implemented but still i get the error

Comment: i'm trying to update an existing object with it's id in another field.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this issue is caused when you try to update an object which is already in use by the current session. For example, if you try to update the User object of currently logged in user. 
To make it work, you will have to create a new hibernate session and use it to update your object.

```
User updatedUser = getAnUpdatedUserObject();
Session session2 = getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx2 = session2.beginTransaction();

session2.saveOrUpdate(updatedUser);

tx2.commit();
session2.close();
```